# Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error'

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is supposed to help me transform many to many relationships into many to one relationships.

For example, if I have a `SKU`, and an order to a certain country attached to that `SKU`, and then a re-currence of that same `country/SKU` combination, I want to create a line by line table that contains JUST the `SKU`, and then in the neighboring cell a comma separated list of values of all the countries that the has sold in. I am getting a **Run-time Application error** on this. I do not know why.

Can someone please take a look at this and help me out when they have a moment?

I have added a couple of stars and errors, indicating *where* the error occurs.

```
Sub SteveOranjin()
    Dim Cl As Range
    '''This is all in VBA for EXCEL:
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each Cl In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then
                .Add Cl.Value, Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                .Item(Cl.Value) = .Item(Cl.Value) & ", " & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
            End If
        Next Cl
        Range("F2").Resize(.Count, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(.keys, .items))  ' ***[error here.]***
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: works for me. BTW use a variable for last row and then use that. `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` gets calculated everytime the loop runs ;)

Comment: Wow wow wow.... can you add a post w/ the new code below?

Comment: How could it be that you're not getting a run time error and I am?

Comment: I used your code.

Comment: Can I see the data? Possibly the file?

Comment: I don't know how you could be getting an error and I'm not. I don't know how to post it online. If you have a place to post files please let me know.

Comment: wikisend.com, google drive, dropbox and so many more

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/756034/Stack_overflow.xlsm

Comment: It's the data type look at that. it doesn't like that some of the numbers are text. How can I stop that in the code?

Comment: One moment. Typing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SteveOranjin()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim arKey, arItm, arFinal

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet   
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With ws
        .Columns("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If Not dict.exists(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, .Range("B" & i).Value
            Else
                dict.Item(.Range("A" & i).Value) = dict.Item(.Range("A" & i).Value) & _
                                                   ", " & .Range("B" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    arKey = dict.Keys: arItm = dict.Items

    ReDim arFinal(LBound(arKey) To UBound(arKey), 0 To 1)

    For i = LBound(arKey) To UBound(arKey)
        arFinal(i, 0) = arKey(i): arFinal(i, 1) = arItm(i)
    Next i

    Range("F2").Resize(UBound(arFinal) + 1, 2) = arFinal
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: It's producing a lot of duplicates. Thats close. So it should come out as

6.813.104   |    Vietnam, Italy, Serbia, Belgium, Portugal, Isreal

Comment: Yes. That is because you are not taking care of it. If you try your original code on a small dataset, you will see that it will create duplicates. The easiest way would be to use `Data Tab | Remove Duplicates` and then run the macro. You can also do it via code by adding the line `Columns("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)` Put the line `.Columns("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)` before `lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` in the above code.

Comment: I tried the "Data Tab | Remove Duplicates" method, and it is still showing multiple instances of Italy, for 6.813.104, even though there is only one instance Italy for 6.813.104 after all of the duplicates have been removed.

Comment: It doesn't like that, I get the same error again. The one that prompted this post.

Comment: I updated the answer. You may have to refresh it to see it. it works. If you are still facing a problem. Close the workbook and reopen it and try it again

Comment: Dude, you saved the day. Thank you.